# Probability of ball hitting the fan

Tags: probability

**Case 1:** A person throws a ball upwards to hit a fan which is not rotating. Let the probability of the event of ball hitting the fan be $p_1$.

**Case 2:** Same person now does the same experiment, this time with a rotating fan. Let the probability of the event this time be $p_2$.

Then what is the relationship between $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: Are we assuming the ball has zero height?

Answer (score 2):

$$P(2)>P(1)$$

In order to exist, the ball must have some radius $r$.

Now, as the ball passes through the plane on which the fan rotates, time passes (the amount depending on both the radius of the ball and its initial velocity).

Given that any amount of time passes while the ball is passing through the plane, even a terribly small amount of time, the fan rotates at least a very small distance, meaning it covers greater area than if angular velocity $\omega=0$.

Thus, the probability $P(2)$ must exceed that of a stationary fan $P(1)$ since having a nonzero radius is a necessary condition for the ball to exist.

Comment: Ok so basically P(2) is a function of the radius of the ball....and as radius approaches 0 P(2) approaches P(1)

Comment: Ya that does make more sense

Comment: Exactly. Also, as the initial velocity approaches infinity, $P(2)$ approaches $P(1)$. 

Since both a radius of zero and infinite velocity present irreconcilable problems, $P(2)$ must exceed $P(1)$.

Comment: Wow....I think I can frame the mathematical equation now...thanks ✌️

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Comment: If the ball needs nonzero radius to exist, then the fan blades also need nonzero thickness to exist.

Comment: This is true as well, though its relatively small thickness would have a minimal effect on $P(2)$

Answer (score 0):

I think both shai horowitz and Lanier Feeman are correct (or wrong) because we don't know external radius, quantity of blades, shape of blades, dimension of the ball.

And when rotating, we don't know rotational speed of fan and ball speed.

And besides, what type of fan?

- electric motors cooling fan
- ceiling fan
- axial box fan
- ....

Answer (score -1):

$p(1)=p (2)$ same percent of ceiling is always covered by the fan at any time

Comment: note this is only when this is all informative given. for instance if he throws a ball straight up always.  if the stationary fan is not above him then p1 = 0 while P2 is not necessarily 0

Comment: Ya...but does that seem intuitive?

Comment: To me it does, what about it is confusing? how can I help? also as pointed out for this to be true we are also assuming ball had zero height